# Combine multiple tuples into a list of tuples

Tags: python, sql, list

I have a series of tuples that are outputed from looping through the results of a SQL query, and its parameters. So far, I have:

```
  Answers = ((userId, p[0], questions, i[0]) for i in strQueryTemplateForAnswerColumn)
            AnswerList = []
            for i in Answers:
                AnswerList.append(i)
                print(AnswerList)
```

Resulting in:

```
[(42, 1, 1, 3)]
[(296, 1, 1, 5)]
[(1358, 1, 1, -1)].....etc for a few thousand rows.
```

What I am trying to do is combine these tuples into one list of tuples rather than each tuple being converted to a list. Such as:

```
[(42, 1, 1, 3), (296, 1, 1, 5), (1358, 1, 1, -1)]
```

This is in order convert it to a pandas df eventually, with 4 columns/headers.

Here is the entire code for reference:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
allSurveyID = cursor.execute("""SELECT SurveyId FROM dbo.[Survey]""").fetchall()

for a in allSurveyID:
p = a
currentSurveyIDs = cursor.execute("""
DECLARE @SurveyID INT = ?
                SELECT *
           FROM
           (
              SELECT
                 SurveyId,
                 QuestionId,
                 1 as InSurvey
              FROM
                 SurveyStructure
              WHERE
                 SurveyId = @SurveyID
              UNION
              SELECT 
                 @SurveyID as SurveyId,
                 Q.QuestionId,
                 0 as InSurvey
              FROM
                 Question as Q
              WHERE NOT EXISTS
              (
                 SELECT *
                 FROM SurveyStructure as S
                 WHERE S.SurveyId = @SurveyID AND S.QuestionId = Q.QuestionId
              )
           ) as t
           ORDER BY QuestionId
            """, p).fetchall()

    for b in currentSurveyIDs:
        survey = (b[0])
        questions = (b[1])
        InSurvey = (b[2])

        allUserID = cursor.execute("""SELECT UserId FROM dbo.[Answer] ORDER BY 
UserId""").fetchall()

        for i in allUserID:
            userId = i[0]

            if InSurvey == 1:
                strQueryTemplateForAnswerColumn = cursor.execute("""SELECT COALESCE 
                                  ((SELECT 
                                   a.Answer_Value
                                   FROM dbo.Answer a 
                                   WHERE a.UserId = ?
                                   AND a.SurveyId = ?
                                   AND a.QuestionId = ?
                                   ),-1) AS ANS_Q?""", userId, survey, questions, questions).fetchall()

                    Answers = ((userId, p[0], questions, i[0]) for i in 
                                        strQueryTemplateForAnswerColumn)
                    AnswerList = []
                    for i in Answers:
                       AnswerList.append(i)
                       print(AnswerList)
```

Thank you for any input

Comment: Are you looking for the functionality of `extend()` instead of `append()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're saying you have a list of things like `[(42, 1, 1, 3)]` and you want to convert it to a list of things like `(42, 1, 1, 3)`.

You can do this:

```py
listOfListOfTuples = [
    [(42, 1, 1, 3)],
    [(296, 1, 1, 5)],
    [(1358, 1, 1, -1)]
]

print(listOfListOfTuples)

listOfTuples = [x[0] for x in listOfListOfTuples]
print(listOfTuples)
```

Input:

```
[[(42, 1, 1, 3)], [(296, 1, 1, 5)], [(1358, 1, 1, -1)]]
```

Output:

```
[(42, 1, 1, 3), (296, 1, 1, 5), (1358, 1, 1, -1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That's not exactly what I'm after however: My input is [(42, 1, 1, 3)]
[(296, 1, 1, 5)]
[(1358, 1, 1, -1)] as in there are no commas separating each object. Appending each row such as (42,1,1,3) into a list results in a thousand lists containing each object  rather than one list of all the thousand tuples. I'm a bit stuck on how to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but maybe you just need to move the statement `AnswerList = []` to before the start of one of the outer loops: `for i in allUserID:` or `for b in currentSurveyIDs:` or `for a in allSurveyID:`. As a minor comment, I would at a minimum unindent the line `print(AnswerList)` so it is no longer inside the loop `for i in Answers:`.

Comment: I'm finding that changing the indenting results in fewer rows being printed. The problem persists where each printed output is being converted to a list by append rather than having one list of comma separated tuples. When I print the data type, I'm getting: <class 'list'> * 10000. Rather I would like one list containing a thousand tuples.

Comment: To review. You have several nested loops: `for a`, `for b`, `for i` and another `for i` (consider changing inner `for i` to `for answer`). Within `for b`, you initialize `Answers` to a generator of tuples using a comprehension (consider changing `for i` within comprehension to e.g. `for v` to avoid name confusion). In the `for i in Answers` loop, you effectively copy tuples in the generator into the list `AnswerList`. This should do exactly what you want, **except** that you reset `AnswerList` to empty just before the `for i in Answers` loop. Try moving `AnswerList = []` outside all loops?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. This worked.

```
AnswerCol = []
AnswerColNull = []

# Loop through Survey and retrieve SurveyIDs while executing query to return the SurveyIDs, QuestionIDs and whether
# the question is in the survey

for a in allSurveyID:
    p = a[0]
    currentSurveyIDs = cursor.execute("""

                    SELECT *
               FROM
               (
                  SELECT
                     SurveyId,
                     QuestionId,
                     1 as InSurvey
                  FROM
                     SurveyStructure
                  WHERE
                     SurveyId = ?
                  UNION
                  SELECT 
                     ? as SurveyId,
                     Q.QuestionId,
                     0 as InSurvey
                  FROM
                     Question as Q
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS
                  (
                     SELECT *
                     FROM SurveyStructure as S
                     WHERE S.SurveyId = ? AND S.QuestionId = Q.QuestionId
                  )
               ) as t
               ORDER BY QuestionId
                """, p, p, p).fetchall()

    # Assign columns from above query to variables
    for b in currentSurveyIDs:
        survey = (b[0])
        questions = (b[1])
        InSurvey = (b[2])

        # Get all UserIDs and assign to variable
        allUserID = cursor.execute("""SELECT UserId FROM dbo.[Answer] ORDER BY UserId""").fetchall()
        for c in allUserID:
            userId = c[0]

            # If the question is in the survey, proceed with the AnswerColumn template query
            if InSurvey == 1:

                strQueryTemplateForAnswerColumn = cursor.execute("""SELECT COALESCE 
                                      ((SELECT 
                                       a.Answer_Value
                                       FROM dbo.Answer a 
                                       WHERE a.UserId = ?
                                       AND a.SurveyId = ?
                                       AND a.QuestionId = ?
                                       ),-1) AS ANS_Q?""", userId, survey, questions, questions).fetchall()

                # Generate rows for the table by appending each value to a list, creating a row then appending
                # the rows to a list outside the for loop
                Answer_List = []
                for d in strQueryTemplateForAnswerColumn:
                    Answer_parts = userId, p, questions, d[0]
                    Answer_List.append(Answer_parts)
                AnswerColNull.append(Answer_List)

            # Same procedure for the NULL values: if the question is not in the survey, use NULL answer template
            # query
            elif InSurvey == 0:
                strQueryTemplateForNullColumnn = cursor.execute(""" SELECT NULL AS ANS_?""",
                                                                questions).fetchall()
                # Generate rows for the table by appending each value to a list, creating a row then appending
                # the rows to a list outside the for loop
                Answer_ListNull = []
                for e in strQueryTemplateForNullColumnn:
                    Answer_partsNull = userId, p, questions, e[0]
                    Answer_ListNull.append(Answer_partsNull)
                AnswerColNull.append(Answer_ListNull)

# Append the values only of each list, cast to a tuple then appended to another list
AnswerColValsNull = []
for f in AnswerColNull:
    AnswerColValsNull.append(tuple(f[0]))

AnswerColVals = []
for g in AnswerCol:
    AnswerColVals.append(tuple(g[0]))

# Combine the list containing UserID, SurveyID, QuestionID, and Answer_Value
# At this point all the information is in a list of tuples
final = AnswerColVals + AnswerColValsNull
```